# How to open peek window in vscode from a program

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm writing an extension for vscode, in typescript.

In the active editor, at a particular position, I want to open a peek window to display the content of a particular file. Like this one:

[image]

But I can't figure out how to do it. Is it possible? And how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since I found the answer I will post it here in case someone has similar needs.

The name of the built-in command to pop up a peek window is `"editor.action.peekLocations"`. Here is the link to the source file where it is registered. The description in it was enough to make it work:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/editor/contrib/gotoSymbol/goToCommands.ts